# Gain a Customized report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

Goal:
Display the result based on the picture below in reporting Service 2008 R2.

Problem:
How should I do it?

You also have to remember that in reality the list contains lots of data, maybe miljon

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the report itself, this should be a fairly standard implementation.

You'll need to create one **Tablix**, with one **Group** for *Customer* (one row), one **Group** for *Artist* (two rows, one for the headers and one for the *Artist* name, then a detail row for the *Title*.

It looks like you need more formatting options for the *Customers* **Textbox** - you could merge the cells in the *Customer* header row, then insert a **Rectangle**, which will give you more options to move objects around in the row.

For large reports you've got a few options:

**Processing large reports:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159638(v=sql.105).aspx

**Report Snapshots:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156325(v=sql.105).aspx

**Report Caching:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927(v=sql.105).aspx

I would recommend scheduling a **Snapshot** overnight to offload the processing to a quiet time, then making sure the report has sensible pagination set up so not too much data has to be handled at one time when viewed (i.e. not trying to view thousands of reports at one time when viewed in Report Manager).

Another option would be to set up an overnight **Subscription** that could save the report to a fileshare or send it as an email.

Basically you're thinking about reducing the amount of processing that needs to be done at peak times and processing the report once for future use to reduce overall resource usage.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a **List** with text-boxes inside to for that kind of display.
In addition you may consider to add page break after each customer.

Personally I Experienced Lots of performance issues when dealing with thousands of rows, not to mention millions.

My advise to you is to re-consider the report main target: if the report is for exporting purposes - then don't use the ssrs for that.
If the report is for viewing - then perhaps it is possible to narrow down the data using parameters per user's choice.

Last thing, I wish you Good luck :)